# How can I take an Input in Shiny and fill a table with it?

Tags: r, user-input, shiny-server, shiny

I'm attempting to take inputs from various sliders in a Shiny app and consolidate them into a table, however, I keep getting errors such as:

```
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('double', numeric')"


Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "reactive"


Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

I've tried many ideas but cannot get it to work yet. I also haven't found any good examples or explanations to use as guide.

I just need something simple, to fill a table with the result of the sliders, and then be able to print the table via `renderTable()`.

The code that I have that captures the input from the sliders its as follows:

```
sliderInput(inputId = "a.w1.a", label = "Investment on advocacy", min = 0, max = 1000000, step = 50000, value = 0),

sliderInput(inputId = "a.w1.b", label = "Investment on B", min = 0, max = 1000000, step = 50000, value = 0)
```

From that, I was able to create a reactive object that then allowed me to plot successfully:

```
output$fund.a.w1.alloc <- reactive(input$a.w1.a + input$a.w1.b + input$a.w1.c + input$a.w1.d)

output$fund.a.w1.p <- renderPlot(barplot(d.funds.a.w1(), main = "Expenditure strategy (1000's USD)", col = "blue"))
```

But when I try to create a table or a matrix with that same content, I don't seem to get ir right. I have tried stuff like:

```
fund.w1 <- matrix(c(reactive(input$a.w1.a/1000, input$a.w1.b/1000, input$a.w1.c/1000, input$a.w1.d/1000)), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

Or this:

```
fund.w1 <- reactive(matrix(c(input$a.w1.a/1000, input$a.w1.b/1000, input$a.w1.c/1000, input$a.w1.d/1000), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
```

Or this:

```
fund.w1 <- matrix(reactive(c(input$a.w1.a/1000, input$a.w1.b/1000, input$a.w1.c/1000, input$a.w1.d/1000)), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

I even tried to see if the data objects could compose a table by themselves, but it didn't work.

In fact, it didn't even work something as simple as:

```
output$fund.w1.f <- renderTable({input$a.w1.a/1000})
```

Or as (having created the matrix before):

```
fund.w1.f.test[1,1] <- renderText(input$a.w1.a)
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: you will have to include your code in your post, otherwise it's really hard to help!

Comment: That is just the problem. I don't have much of a code for that part because I cannot find anything that works. I'll add some of my previous attempts to the original question and see it that can help you to help me. Thank you very much for your disposition! I really appreciate.

Comment: Hi, @MLavoie, just made the changes to try to clarify the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out how to get it to work (sorry if this was too basic, guys, I'm fairly new to Shiny and still getting the handle on things).

I found an example which led me to extrapolate that after building the data `reactive` object:

```
d.funds.c.w1 <- reactive(c(input$c.w1.c/1000, input$c.w1.a/1000, input$c.w1.b/1000)
```

Then, to get it into a table, you needed to use `renderTable()` as follows:

```
output$fund.w1.f <- renderTable({
  d <- data.frame(x = rbind(t(o.funds.a.w1()), t(o.funds.b.w1()), t(o.funds.c.w1()), t(o.funds.d.w1())))
  d
})
```

Another way to go about it is like [an answer I just got](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/fill$20table/shiny-discuss/gsJI_Elyqhw/dPyrjDMQAwAJ) from a guy called Ben Newberg in the Shiny forums group in Google, where I posted the same question :

`Turn the slider input values into a data frame first.`

```
sliderInput(inputId = "a.w1.a", label = "Investment on advocacy", min = 0, max = 1000000, step = 50000, value = 0),
sliderInput(inputId = "a.w1.b", label = "Investment on B", min = 0, max = 1000000, step = 50000, value = 0),
tableOutput("tbl")


output$tbl <- renderTable({
   df1 <- data.frame(a = c(input$a.w1.a), b = c(input$a.w1.b))
   df1
})
```

I hope this helps anyone that might need the same kind of guidance.